# Advanced Filtering with Firestore React native

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to implement a filtering functionality to my app. I am currently making realtime queries using firestore. In my app, I have 5 filtering options and I would like the user to be able to make any combination of filtering they desire and displays the available data based on their filter query.

Comment: Sounds like a cool use-case. What is your question for us? --- If you already tried implementing the use-case yourself, it is much more likely someone can help if you edit your question and show a [minimal reproduction](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of where you got stuck.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the response I got this resolved. I just had to do a bunch of if-else statements.

Comment: I'm having the same issue here, could you please help me with your solution?

Comment: Hey @YassineAkermi, I ended up switching to AWS Amplify